# R - mxnet RNN "Incompatible attr in node at 0-th output"

Tags: r, recurrent-neural-network, mxnet

I'm working a multi-layer RNN for a word-level language model. It has a one-to-one configuration so that for each step in the training set a prediction is validated against an eval set of the same dimensions. The model borrows almost entirely from the example laid out [here](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/tutorials/r/charRnnModel.html) but adapted for word-level modeling. My variation is [here](https://github.com/connermcb/next_word_predictor/blob/master/small_rnn.R).

Another difference is between the example script linked above is the data I'm working with has multiple buckets. I believe that I've bucketed the data correctly but when it's fed to `mx.model.buckets`, I get some variation of this error:

```
Start training with 1 devices
Error in exec$update.arg.arrays(arg.arrays, match.name, skip.null) : 
  [17:25:59] `c:\jenkins\workspace\mxnet\mxnet\src\operator\tensor\../elemwise_op_common.h:123: Check failed: assign(&dattr, (*vec)[i]) Incompatible attr in node  at 0-th output: expected [32,7], got [32,8]`
```

The issue appears to be a mismatch between the actual and expected input dimensions. The batch size is 32, and the values of 7 and 8 appear related to consecutive buckets in `bucket.plan`.

```
train_data <- mx.io.bucket.iter(buckets = train_buckets$buckets,
                                batch.size = batch_size, 
                                data.mask.element = 0, shuffle = TRUE)

eval_data <- mx.io.bucket.iter(buckets = eval_buckets$buckets,
                               batch.size = batch_size,
                               data.mask.element = 0, shuffle = TRUE)
```

From the iterators above, I can pull the batch and bucket data:

```
> head(train_data$bucket.plan, 10)
 8  9 10  3 22 10 10  8 15 21 
 1  1  1  1  1  2  3  2  1  1 
> train_data$batch
[1] 1
> train_data$bucketID
8 
1
```

The value at `train_data$batch` is used in `bucket.iter` as an index for pulling the next bucket name from `train_data$bucket.plan`:

```
iter.next = function() {
        .self$batch <- .self$batch + 1
        .self$bucketID <- .self$bucket.plan[batch]
```

The bucket names correspond the length of the sentences assigned to them minus 1. So for bucket 8, the batch dimension should be [32, 7], what the training function expects. But as stated in the error it's actually picking up the input dimensions for `bucket.plan[2]`.

On other occasions, the first batch trains successfully only to have an error thrown on the second batch in which the input dimensions for the bucket at `bucket.plan[n]` are expected, but the dimensions for `bucket.plan[n-1]` are returned instead:

```
Start training with 1 devices
Error in exec$update.arg.arrays(arg.arrays, match.name, skip.null) : 
  [17:37:53] c:\jenkins\workspace\mxnet\mxnet\src\operator\tensor\../elemwise_op_common.h:123: Check failed: assign(&dattr, (*vec)[i]) Incompatible attr in node  at 0-th output: expected [32,42], got [32,10]
> head(train_data$bucket.plan, 10)
11 43  8  6  7  3  6 12 15 12 
 1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  2 
> train_data$batch
[1] 2
> train_data$bucketID
43 
 1
```

There doesn't appear to be a mismatch between the data and labels:

```
> dim(train_data$buckets[[names(train_data$bucketID)]]$data)
[1]  42 186
> dim(train_data$buckets[[names(train_data$bucketID)]]$label)
[1]  42 186
```

The scripts that I believe are at issue here are [incubator-mxnet/R-package/R/mx.io.bucket.iter.R](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/R-package/R/mx.io.bucket.iter.R) and [incubator-mxnet/R-package/R/executor.R](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/R-package/R/executor.R). For some reason, the indices for iterating through `bucket.plan` appear not to be updating correctly.

I've found some other threads on this topic, but nothing that has helped me resolve the error.

Any ideas?